# Application Loader, new weird warning about Signiant Transfer Engine

Tags: ios, application-loader

Application Loader shown me a weird warning message instead of the check-in-big-green-circle before the "Thank you" dialog.

"Creating a new Signiant Transfer Engine because the previous transfer had to be canceled. This session is at risk of running out of available system resources."

I used Application Loader 2.5.2 on OS X Lion 10.7.3.

In the Activity window, all seemed good and the binary itself has been uploaded to the iTunes Connect, the app status goes Waiting For Review.

Has anyone experienced this?

Comment: I haven't used the Signiant Transfer Engine myself, but alternative file transfer methods like those used by Signiant and FileCatalyst can usually be tuned in terms of ports being used, threads being used for the transfer, size of payload, etc. which consume varying amounts of CPU and RAM. Perhaps it is noticing that there is not enough RAM to handle the particular task? In which case you can probably ask it to be more conservative.

Comment: Thanks, Greg.  I'm not sure what the Signiant Transfer Engine is. Only thing I know is that Signiant name is available as one of Delivery mechanism with Aspera and DAV in Preferences.../Advanced. Al is checked and it looks like a don't-touch-setting.
---
update1: The app has passed the review.
update2: I've got a message from Apple support telling me to file it as a bug.

Comment: Oh, I thought you had intentionally installed Signiant at some point. Signiant and Aspera are both file delivery mechanisms that replace FTP or HTTP based transfers. They're not default delivery mechanisms in any OS or application other than their own, so at some point they have been installed or a media creation or production or workflow application has used their APIs in order to use them for delivery directly from the application.

Comment: @NaohiroTsuji Did you ever hear back from Apple? I got the same warning.

Comment: @zLan did YOU ever hear back from Apple? I got the same warning aswell. :)

Comment: @Spoek I never heard back, but I've submitted apps with that warning and I haven't seen any issues.

Comment: @zla Im getting the same warning was your app approved?? I can read that NaohiroTsuji's app was approved.

Comment: @holierthanthou84 It got approved and I didn't notice any issues with the app.

Comment: @zla Thats a reliever :) Thank you so much for the response!

Answer (score 9):

Same error message "Creating a new Signiant Transfer Engine because the previous transfer had to be canceled. This session is at risk of running out of available system resources."

1. I had this message after a chaotic upload of a 120 Mb app to the AppStore, using Application loader v2.7 (273), and MacOSX 10.7.3. Searching for my SKU in "Window->Lookup Status..." menu item dialog box, I noticed that there had been several Failures ("Upload Failed"), including at least one time, I decided to push the "Cancel" button in order to reboot my machine, so much this upload was slow.
2. I have noticed that the Application Loader JAVA engine may still be running in the background when you quit the Application Loader application, and that it is no more visible in the "Force to quit..." list. I use a packet surveyor called "Little Snitch" that showed this JAVA engine running while only Finder was opened.

So to summarize: this message may be shown when you have cancelled one of your uploads, and just restarted a new one while the previous one (performed by a background task) was still running in background. This generates a "Warning" message, but not an error, thus, instead of the green "OK", you have a notification of the warnings, just like in XCode.

Comment: I had faced same problem got same warning message.Also i got this in iTunes connect shows me "ready for review" my app. So my doubt is this warning may give me problem while apple reviewing my application?

Comment: Application Loader is ver.2.8 now. After 2.7, I have no trouble with the app for more than ten times in uploading ipa files.

Comment: It is major issue or not.

Comment: it might be the right answer, but it doesn't tell me how to solve the problem... my app has been rejected by apple after the upload...

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem.it been solved with going to Application loader->Prereference and uncheck the Signiant option.