# updating my iOS app in appStore - Signiant Transfer Engine warning - app got rejected

Tags: ios, xcode, appstore-approval

I've submitted and updated my app successfully several times. Now when I'm uploading my app via XCode Organizer (not application Loader) I receive the following warning (3 times):

"Creating a new Signiant Transfer Engine because the previous transfer had to be canceled. This session is at risk of running out of available system resources."

First I didn't think much about it, but today the App got rejected  by the App Store reviewer because it crashes on launch on the iPad air they use to test on.
Any ideas how this can be solved?
I found this discussion here: [Application Loader, new weird warning about Signiant Transfer Engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10548196/application-loader-new-weird-warning-about-signiant-transfer-engine) which suggests to change the preferences in Application loader. But because I have not uploaded my App via application loader from the beginning I cannot use application loader to update it (at least I couldn't figure out how), so it doesn't help me. 
What else could be going wrong? Any ideas welcome!

update: the app validates without errors and warnings. when uploading it it takes much longer than usual before I get the warning mentioned above. I have tested the app on multiple devices. Also the app is actually not targeting iPads, it's mainly made for iPhone/iPodtouch.
It works fine on all. The link above suggests that not all files are uploaded correctly when the error message occurs. So that could be the problem. But the question is how to change it...

Comment: Have you tried your app on an iPad? Sorry for the basic question but... Just in case...

Comment: its targeted for iPhone only. so why does it have to work on iPad then?

Comment: All apps need to run on iPad too. Even though the app is not universal, it must run on all possible devices.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but I don't think the warning has anything to do with the crash or your app being rejected.

You could file a TSI with Apple, but I would try to find the crashing bug first. https://developer.apple.com/support/technical/submit/

Comment: XCode doesn't even give out any other warnings. The app validates perfectly fine but then it takes much longer than usual to upload and I get this weird error. I've tested the app on multiple devices. it works fine on all... (haven't tested on ipad air but ipad...)