# Creating a new Signiant Transfer Engine because the previous transfer had to be canceled

Tags: ios, appstore-approval

I submitted app on app store but there is warning **"Creating a new Signiant Transfer Engine because the previous transfer had to be canceled. This session is at risk of running out of available system resources."**
Is there any problem regarding this ? 
[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Application Loader, new weird warning about Signiant Transfer Engine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10548196/application-loader-new-weird-warning-about-signiant-transfer-engine)

Comment: Is there any chances to reject app because of this ?

Answer (score 1):

Exact screen showed up for me while submitting a new version. I tried cleaning the build folder even cleaned the project, re-archived from scratch. Doesn't shows up anything in validation. I've submitted the app, lets see how it goes. As to why it happens I don't know. Apparantly, there's an option to uncheck "Signiant Transfer Engine" via Application Loader Preferences, but to do so via Organiser I have no clue.

Did you submitted your app? If so best of luck and do let us know how it went?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Actually my app becomes live at friday. SO there is no issue with those warnings.

Comment: Thank god!! Thats a reliever :)

Comment: Actually this warning due to cancellation of submission. So if you cancel submission then you validate your product again and re submit app. This warning never will come.

Comment: Funny! Yes I did reject the binary. But then I revalidated the app and submitted yet it showed up.. Maybe I missed out on something