# Xcode upload error: Failed to open ssh session. (16)

Tags: ios, xcode, ssh, webdav, xcode5.1

***NOTE:*** We finally uploaded the app but we didn't really troubleshoot this issue so I would appreciate if someone could share some valuable insight or experience pertaining to this question.

*I've also checked the following 2 similar questions but these **didn't** help:*

- *[Error uploading ios application to itunesconnect “failed to open ssh session (16)”](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24120220/2857130)*
- *[App Store submission/distribution error “failed to open ssh session”](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22288516/2857130)*

---

### So...

Firstly, I am on a company network and just a week back we published a fresh new app using Max OSX 10.9.3 (13D65) & Xcode v5.1.1 (5B1008).

This week, while trying to upload an update for this app via the same system, I ran into a few issues.

---

### 1st try<sup>*firewalled</sup>

[image: Unable to connect to sgr203.apple.com:44001]

---

### 2nd/3rd try<sup>*firewalled</sup>

So, I got our network admin to open up port number 44001 and tried again.
Although it did reduce the number of errors, it failed again.
[image: Failed to open ssh session. (16)]
Thought we'd try from another system but same error.

---

### 4th try<sup>*firewalled</sup>

NOTE: No changes in network or system
[image: Failed to open ssh session. (16)]

---

### 5th try<sup>*firewall bypassed</sup>

So, I got our network admin to look into it and eventually we ended up bypassing the company firewall just for this upload session but it failed again.
[image: Failed to open ssh session. (16)]

---

### 6th try<sup>*firewalled</sup>

Thought we'd try from another system again so I switched to a colleague's system that hadn't been involved in this app's development, note that it was **not** bypassing the firewall, and it uploaded successfully in it's 1st attempt, albeit with a few warnings.

- System was a Mac OSX 10.9.3 that we later realized had an older version of Xcode (5.0) but anyways...

[image: ...checksum validation failed]

---

Would someone be kind enough to shed some light or hints for the following errors/warnings:

1. Error: `Failed to open ssh session. (16)` <sup>(*NOTE: this appeared with/without firewall/restrictions*)</sup>
2. Error: `Could NOT set the remote path to the existing package`
3. Error: `Could not create/set the package's folder on Apple's webDAV`
4. <strike>[Warning: `Creating a new Signiant Transfer Engine`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10548196/2857130)</strike>

---

Answer (score 8):

After having the same issue I've been able to fix this issue.

To solve this issue you need to:

1. Go to page 6 "System and Network Requirements" from https://itunesconnect.apple.com/docs/UsingApplicationLoader.pdf
2. verify that all of the ports and IP addresses are accessible.

After opening all of the ports from the table, I'm now able to upload my apps.

Enjoy!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem when using my company's network because we use a proxy and due to security reasons all the needed ports and IPs reported on the [official documentation](https://itunesconnect.apple.com/docs/UsingApplicationLoader.pdf) were blocked. After switching to an external network without proxies, I was able to upload my new app.