# iOS publish errors to App Store using application loader

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms

This is my first time publishing an iOS app. I did everything correctly as far as the app id, provision certificates and iTunes connect setup. Upon publishing using Application Loader, I keep facing these errors even though i've added the correct images.

> ERROR ITMS-90000: "This bundle is invalid. The PNG file is too small to be a valid image: icon.png."

[image]

[image]

Comment: start by changing the referred images with ones with the correct size and try again

Comment: Can you show proof of the images being correct?

Comment: Please check my edit. I've attached a screenshot of my resource folder. I realized the images they've mentioned are the default ones. Is it fine to delete them ?

Answer (score 0):

> The session's status is FAILED and the error description is 'failed to open ssh session.(16)'

1. Launch the Application Loader from Xcode: Choose Xcode > Open Developer Tool > Application Loader from the menu bar. The last version of Application Loader is `3.7`.
2. Change a network to have a try. If your network use a proxy, it may generate this issue too. Here's a [list of Apple servers](http://help.apple.com/itc/apploader/#/itc8e7ec5a60), make sure you can access to them.

> ERROR ITME-90000:"This bundle is invalid. The PNG file is too small to be a valid image: ...
>
> I realized the images they've mentioned are the default ones. Is it fine to delete them ?

- If you already have the `AppIcon` image set in the `Assets.xcassets` folder, you can remove them. Make sure you have imported the required size icon image in the AppIcon image set. And you have to set the `AppIcon` image set as the **Source** of App Icons at **info.plist->App Icons**.

> WARNING ITMS-90717:" Invalid App Store Icon. The app store icon in the asset catalog in can't be transparent nor contain an alpha channel."

- If there's no alpha and transparency with your icons, it may be a bug from Apple, see the [case](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/86829). Changing the "Deployment Target" to 8.0 or higher may solve that according to that case.

References:

- [Xcode upload error: Failed to open ssh session. (16)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25169034/xcode-upload-error-failed-to-open-ssh-session-16)
- [The session's status is FAILED and the error description is 'failed to open ssh session](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/51661/the-sessions-status-is-failed-and-the-error-description-is-failed-to-open-ssh-session-16)